# Proof about the equation ax + by = c

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given $ax +by = c$ and $d= \gcd(a,b)$, where $a,b,c,d,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, prove the following:

A. if c does not divide d, the equation has no solution.

B. if d divide c the equation has Infinity solutions.

I need to prove that there is at least one solution, each t has a solution And does not miss a solution.

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: But there's no d in this equation.

Comment: I think $d$ is  the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @אוהד כהן, are you familiar with the Bezout's Identity (or Bezout's Lemma) in elementary number theory?

Comment: yes I know Bezout's Identity, But I dont know how to prove what they wanted.

Comment: You should add that the equation is over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: You "A." statement should start with "if d does not divide c", i.e., you have the $c$ and $d$ mixed around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\gcd(a,b)=d\implies ax+by=dex+dfy=d(ex+fy)$$Which has a divisor of d, so if c doesn't, it can't solve the sum.

For the second part, $$ex+fy=\frac{c}{d}$$ and $$e(x+f)+f(y-e)=ex+fy+fe-fe$$ in which the last two terms cancel, adding 0 in the process. So you can change x and y by set amounts, in opposite directions, and get the same answer, creating a chain of solutions that never ends. Therefore, there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if $d=$gcd$(a,b)$ then $$a= a'\cdot d\qquad b=b'\cdot d$$ Therefore, your equation becomes

> $$ax+by=a'dx+b'dy=d\cdot (a'x+b'y)=c\quad\fbox{$\implies d\mid c$}$$

---

For the second part, consider the algorithm

> $$(x, y)\to (x+b't, y-a't)$$

for an arbitrary $t\in \Bbb Z$, which generates an infinite set of solutions

Comment: But how does it prove that if d does not divide c then the equation has no solution? – אוהד כהן 1 min ago    Edit

Comment: Should I show only this line of the algorithm?